# Adding information to the namespace of XML generated by the JAXB marshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to marshal an object, which produces the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Jetstream xmlns="http://Jetstream.TersoSolutions.com/v1.0/HeartbeatEvent">......
```

My desired output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Jetstream xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://Jetstream.TersoSolutions.com/v1.0/HeartbeatEvent">
```

I am marshaling the object using the following code

```
    JAXBContext context;

    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(heartbeat.getClass());
        OutputStream writer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");


        heartbeat.setHeader(header);
        heartbeat.setHeartbeatEvent(event);

        marshaller.marshal(heartbeat, writer);
        String stringXML = writer.toString();
        return stringXML;

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problems generating XML in specified "
                + "encoding, underlying problem is " + e.getMessage(),
                e);
```

Adding

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

will cause output to be close to expected, except in the wrong order and with the wrong prefix

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Jetstream xmlns="http://Jetstream.TersoSolutions.com/v1.0/HeartbeatEvent" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">...
```

I would like to ask for some assistance with generating my namespace in the proper order and with the correct prefixes.

**EDIT**

After following the advice in the comment I still haven't had any luck. I added the following to my package-info.java file in the relevant package.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://Jetstream.TersoSolutions.com/v1.0/HeartbeatEvent",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="xsd", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") })
```

and my resulting output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ns2:Jetstream xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://Jetstream.TersoSolutions.com/v1.0/HeartbeatEvent">
```

for some reason the prefix was cut short, and now there are ns2: tags throughout the xml. These tags cannot be present.

Comment: see if this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7736235/1043824 helps you

Comment: After reviewing the thread and attempting a solution I am slightly closer and my findings have been added to the thread. I still do not have the desired solution.