# How to set the namespace of marshalled xml using camel jaxb?

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, jbossfuse

For starters, I'm creating some routes using Camel ver 2.15 (in Fuse 6.2.1).

In my route, i'm trying to create a XML from a pojo that was generated using cxf-xjc maven plugin (cxf-xjc read some xsd somewhere then from the xsd, the pojos with jaxb annotations were produced).

The pojos are TempProject and TempProjects.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
name = "",
propOrder = {"ecode", "tempName"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
name = "TempProject"
)
public class TempProject implements Serializable {
@XmlElement(
    name = "Ecode",
    required = true
)
protected String ecode;
@XmlElement(
    name = "TempName",
    required = true
)
protected String tempName;

public TempProject() {
}

public String getEcode() {
    return this.ecode;
}

public void setEcode(String value) {
    this.ecode = value;
}

public String getTempName() {
    return this.tempName;
}

public void setTempName(String value) {
    this.tempName = value;
}
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
name = "",
propOrder = {"tempProjects"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
name = "TempProjects"
)
public class TempProjects implements Serializable {
@XmlElement(
    name = "TempProject",
    required = true
)
protected List<TempProject> tempProjects;

public TempProjects() {
}

public List<TempProject> getTempProjects() {
    if (this.tempProjects == null) {
        this.tempProjects = new ArrayList();
    }

    return this.tempProjects;
}
}
```

I can generate the xml using this code:

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{TempProjects.class}); 
 jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
 JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext); //import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat;
```

I call

```
.marshal(jaxbDataFormat)
```

in my route to effect the marshalling from the pojo to xml.

The generated xml is posted below:

```
<TempProjects xmlns="http://blah.blah/foo/schema/v2">
<TempProject>
    <Ecode>1</Ecode>
    <TempName>Tempname1</TempName>
</TempProject>
<TempProject>
    <Ecode>2</Ecode>
    <TempName>Tempname2</TempName>
</TempProject>
```

How can i generate a marshalled xml that will have a namespace like this...

```
<TempProjects xmlns:myprefix="http://blah.blah/foo/schema/v2">
```

Reason being why I needed a namespaceprefix is because I plan to *split* the values (e.g. Ecode) in the xml using xpath and I needed a namespaceprefix to do that (thats what ive researched, i might be wrong).

My planned code in my route is

```
.marshal(jaxbDataFormat)
.split( xpath("/TempProjects/TempProject/Ecode/text()").namespaces(ns1), 
new ProjectIdsAggregator()) //the above xpath doesn't work because it doesn't have a namespace prefix

//Namespaces ns1 = new Namespaces("myprefix", "http://blah.blah/foo/schema/v2" );
```

I looked at jaxbDataFormat.setNamespacePrefixRef("myprefix"), but i got an error (*org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: myprefix of type: java.util.Map*)

I'm actually quite new in the apache camel routing world, so i might be missing some basic stuff.

Comment: Your xpath works without .namespaces(ns1) with default xml. Have you some problems when run route without namespaces ?

Comment: @c0ld It doesnt work, i can still see the whole xml in the log after the split()...   
split[XPath: /TempProjects/TempProject/Ecode/text()] --> stop <<< Pattern:InOut, BodyType:byte[], Body:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TempProjects xmlns="http://blah.blah/foo/schema/v2">
    <TempProject>
        <Ecode>1</Ecode>
        <TempName>Tempname1</TempName>
    </TempProject>
    <TempProject>
        <Ecode>2</Ecode>
        <TempName>Tempname2</TempName>
    </TempProject>
</TempProjects>

Comment: Inattentively readed =) Answer about jaxb u cant find here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895486/jaxb-need-namespace-prefix-to-all-the-elements
but better way is answer by @burki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need to change your XML** at all. It is fine.

With the XML you posted and the Namespace declaration you posted, the following XPath works fine to split the XML (as an example) into two `TempProject` parts:

```
xpath("/myprefix:TempProjects/myprefix:TempProject").namespaces(ns1)
```

Because you declared the XML namespace like this:

```
Namespaces ns1 = new Namespaces("myprefix", "http://blah.blah/foo/schema/v2" )
```

Your XPath must use the prefix `myprefix` for all elements:

```
/myprefix:TempProjects/myprefix:TempProject
```