# Define namespaces tags so that generated XML have those tags?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have two classes People.java and PeopleMain.java

People.java

```
package com.test;

public class People {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }   

}
```

PeopleMain.java

```
package com.test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class PeopleMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        People p= new People();

        p.setAge("21");
        p.setName("Manish Sharma");

        XStream xs =new XStream();

        String xml = xs.toXML(p);

        System.out.println(xml);    
    }
}
```

My output on console on running PeopleMain.java comes as:

```
<com.test.People>
  <name>Manish Sharma</name>
  <age>21</age>
</com.test.People>
```

but I want an output as

```
<People xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/foo" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/bar">
  <ns2:name>Manish Sharma</ns2:name>
  <ns3:age>21</ns3:age>
</People>
```

What changes should I make in my People.java file to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, per the [XSTream FAQ](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#XML_namespaces), XStream does not support XML namespaces unless using a StAX parser**.

> Not every XML parser supports namespaces and not every XML parser that
>   supports namespaces can be configured within XStream to use those.
>   Basically namespaces must be supported individually for the different
>   XML parsers and the only support for namespaces that has currently
>   been implemented in XStream is for the StAX paser. Therefore use and
>   configure the StaxDriver of XStream to use namespaces.

Comment: okk, Can i do it through JaxB , if yes please post an answer to do it through that, here Xstream is not important for me  and thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, JAXB can do namespaces; see [JAXB namespaces missing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6294065/290085).

Comment: sorry but that doesn't tell how to put two different namespaces in .java file , There is only one namespace ns0.

Comment: If that question isn't exactly what you want, look through the links in the **Related** section there.  If none of those fit your situation, you should ask a new question rather than extend this conversation in comments.    Thanks.

Comment: please answer my next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250501/how-to-use-jaxb-to-output-an-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: There's already a fine answer there by JAXB master Blaise Doughan.  Go with it.