# How to use JAXB to output an xml with Namespaces?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

May be I am repeating this question as compared to previous question([Define namespaces tags so that generated XML have those tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250036/define-namespaces-tags-so-that-generated-xml-have-those-tags)), but since in my previous question this scope gets limited to XStream that is why I need to ask this new question.

I have two classes People.java and PeopleMain.java

People.java

```
package com.test;

public class People {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }   

}
```

PeopleMain.java

```
package com.test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class PeopleMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        People p= new People();

        p.setAge("21");
        p.setName("Manish Sharma");

        String xml = //JAXB code to get xml from Person p object

        System.out.println(xml);    
    }
}
```

My output on console on running PeopleMain.java comes as:

```
<com.test.People>
  <name>Manish Sharma</name>
  <age>21</age>
</com.test.People>
```

but I want an output as

```
<People xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/foo" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/bar">
  <ns2:name>Manish Sharma</ns2:name>
  <ns3:age>21</ns3:age>
</People>
```

What changes should I make in my People.java file to get the desired output?

Comment: If you write "Please don't downvote and answer" you might already guess that its not quite a good question after all. Maybe you want to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following and specify the namespace on the `@XmlElement` annotation:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="People")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class People {

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://example.com/foo")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://example.com/bar")
    private int age;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html