# How do I tell the JAXB marshaller to use the schemaLocation provided in my beans' package-info?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to get my JAXB marshaller to use the provided schemaLocation *without* using

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "some location");
```

I see that there is an option to provide a schema location in my 
package descriptor

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://my.website.com/TheClass"
  , elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
  , location = "http://my.website.com/TheClass TheClass.xsd"
)
package com.mypackage.beans;
```

but it won't print in the xml

Comment: What if you use `location = "TheClass.xsd"` in the annotation?

Comment: what is wrong in `marshaller.setProperty` ?

Comment: @approxiblue - no dice, same result

Comment: @ulab - I don't have access to the signature that calls the marshaller. I can change the mashaller code if i need to but I can't pass a location to it every time I want to marshall a bean

Comment: How do you build your JAXB context?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your main issue is that the generated XML from your marshaller misses the required name space.

Have you tried adding the `xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="your_name_space", namespaceURI="http://my.website.com/TheClass")}`
in your `XmlSchema` annotation in your package descriptor?

(Suggestion taken from: [JAXB namespace prefixes missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294065/jaxb-namespace-prefixes-missing))

Comment: It looks like that just changes the default namespace to one that I can specify. (so all my elements look like `<myNamespace:Element>` instead of `<Element>`.

But it doesn't do anything with the schema location